# Big decimal setScale gives different value some times

Tags: java

I am trying to limit my Amount fields to 4 decimal points by using below,

`String val = new BigDecimal(amt).setScale(4,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString()`

However this gives inconsistent result some times, In some cases I can see the same value is getting to 2.9719 or it becomes 2.9720. What could be issue

Comment: Can you show example, please?

Comment: @Michu93 IT happens randomly only for some records, not sure of exact pattern. Is there a possibility that ```RoundingMode.HALF_UP``` can return different value for same Amount field

Comment: what is the datatype of amt ? How is that set ?

Comment: No part of this code should return a different answer for the same input different times, but it's possible `amt` is differing in some subtle way.